# MongoDB replicaset nodes changing from primary to secondary

Tags: mongodb

whenever a node changing his status from primary to secondary it will ask me to run rs.secondaryOk() in order to be able to use the secondary for read/ show dbs / show users...
Is this normal? how can I force that it won't need to run this command everytime it changes a status?

Answer (score 0):

You should be "connecting to the replica set". See your driver documentation for how to do that. Then your queries will be automatically routed to the current primary.